# Check if array is Codable

Tags: swift, swift4

I have a function below:

```
func check(_ type: Any.Type) {
        switch type {
           case is [String].Type
        ...
      }
}
```

For example:

```
class TaskContainer: Codable {
    let id: String
    let tasks: [String]
}
typealias TaskContainers = [TaskContainer]
check(TaskContainers.self)
```

How to check if an array is Codable?

Not working:

- case is [Codable].Type
- case is Array[Codable].Type

Comment: Why do you need to check that? You made the array; how can you not know whether its element is Codable?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that `[TaskContainer].Type` is a subtype of `[Codable].Type`, but it is not. What you are trying to do is highly unusual. If you tell us more about why you want to do this, maybe we can suggest a better way.

Comment: Almost anything you try here is likely to be unreliable, even if you get it working. Much of Swift is statically dispatched, so it will make choices at compile-time, not runtime. The fact that you are passing around `Any.Type` at all suggests a very deep type problem in your code. You should back up and think through the problem you're actually trying to solve, and we should be able to help you.

Comment: @robmayoff, it's a function in PerfectPostgreSQL. I need to add new type(Array of Codable objects) /

Comment: I took a quick look at [Perfect-PostgreSQL](https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-PostgreSQL/blob/master/Sources/PerfectPostgreSQL/PerfectPostgreSQL.swift) and found no functions named `check`. Edit your question to show us how you're trying to use the library and what errors are occurring.

Comment: @robmayoff, Sorry, I was wrong. It's [Perfect-CRUD](https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-CRUD/blob/master/Sources/PerfectCRUD/Coding/Coding.swift).  In public enum SpecialType {}

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have time to figure out why Perfect-CRUD is implemented that way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the reason for checking but this should work.

```
if let _ = TaskContainers.self as? Codable.Type {
    // Conforms to Codable protocol.
}
```